# Neo4j Cypher query - query property array with regular expression

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database (2.0.3). I am currently using Cypher to run some test queries on my dataset. I have a set of records that have a property containing an array of names. I want to be able to search this array of names, while also using a basic reg-ex to do so. Is this at all possible within cypher? If not how do you reccommend going about this?

Something that would combine both of these queries:

```
 MATCH (s:Record) WHERE "John" IN s.name RETURN s;
 MATCH (s:Record) WHERE s.name =~ '(?i).*john.*)' RETURN s;
```

Comment: The old indexes of Neo4j treat an array property as individual entries, so if you need a high performance version of that, check out: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following example data:

```
CREATE (:Record {name: ['John', 'Bob']}),
       (:Record {name: ['Alice', 'Johnny']}),
       (:Record {name: ['the johnster', 'Charles']}),
       (:Record {name: ['Danny', 'Josh']})
```

If you want to find all Records where *any* of the elements in the property array `name` matches a regexp, use `ANY`. If you want to find all Records where *all* elements in the property array `name` match a regexp, use `ALL`. I believe you want the former:

```
MATCH (s:Record)
WHERE ANY(name IN s.name WHERE name =~ '(?i).*john.*')
RETURN s.name
```

This returns:

```
s.name
John, Bob
Alice, Johnny
the johnster, Charles
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Nicole. Just incase others have this question. In the case I outlined, ANY is the correct keyword, as Nicole said.